# LegendFormat error in dashboard grafana yaml

Tags: prometheus, grafana

i am getting this error below

function {{phase}} not found

i got this json from dashboard and it works but yaml doesn't work either

```
        {
          "datasource": {
            "type": "xxx",
            "uid": "xxx"
          },
          "editorMode": "code",
          "exemplar": false,
          "expr": "kube_pod_status_phase{job=\"xxxx\", namespace=\"$namespace\", pod=~\"$cronjob-.*\", phase=~\"Succeeded|Running|Failed\"} * on(namespace, pod) group_left() max without(job, phase) (kube_pod_status_phase)",
          "format": "heatmap",
          "instant": true,
          "interval": "",
          "legendFormat": "{{phase}}",
          "range": false,
          "refId": "A"
        }
```